# jQuery / jQuery UI throwing up a console get error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, web-inspector

I get the following console get error my page

```
GET http://www.website.com/mypage/none 404 (Not Found) jquery.min.js:3 a.getComputedStyle.Jb jquery.min.js:3
m.extend.css jquery.min.js:3
m.each.m.cssHooks.(anonymous function).set jquery.min.js:3
m.extend.style jquery.min.js:3
 (anonymous function) jquery.min.js:4
m.access jquery.min.js:3
m.each.m.each.m.fn.(anonymous function) jquery.min.js:4
 (anonymous function) jquery-ui.min.js:146
$.ui jquery-ui.min.js:1
(anonymous function) jquery-ui.min.js:16
```

Even though I'm using the following to include the javascript.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error shown in the console indicates the following filename:

```
jquery.min.js:3
```

Whereas in your question you said that you have included this which is a different filename:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

It looks like you have included some other version of jQuery somewhere else in your website. Remove this inclusion to avoid referencing jQuery multiple times.

Same stands true for jQuery UI. The error indicates `jquery-ui.min.js` whereas you have included `<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>`

Comment: Sorry, yes `jquery.min.js` is the same as `jquery-1.11.2.min.js` I had a local copy to see if it was a cdn problem.